# How to add a small triangle at one of the corners of QWidget?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I get a small triangle in left bottom corner or right top corner of the QPushButton I am using. I am not sure how it is showing up. I am just using simple PushButton. I needed same kind of thing for my custom widget derived from QWidget.

I wanted to know is there any flag to set this or do I need to implement explicitly ? Looks like a page turn symbol we see in some online pdf's.

I am kind of new to Qt. Please answer.

Comment: You can use `QWidget::setStyleSheet` to set a background with a picture you need.

Comment: I am trying to use stylesheet, but i am not able to set the image properly. Its not showing up atleast.
I am trying to do it this way. Let me know if i am doing any mistake there.

m_pWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/icons/Drill_progress_marker_left.svg); background-position: top right");

Answer (score 0):

The small triangle indicates that the QPushButton has a popup menu associated: [QPushButton::setMenu()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#setMenu).

If you want to add a triangle, you can use stylesheet or reimplement `QWidget::paintEvent()` to paint the triangle in a corner. A basic example:

```
void Widget::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* event ) {
    QWiudget::paintEvent( event );
    QPainter painter( this );
    QPolygon p();
    p.append( QPoint(10, 10) );
    p.append( QPoint(14, 10) );
    p.append( QPoint(12, 14) );
    painter.drawPolygon( p );
}
```

But, I think, a better solution would be adding a `QPushButton` to your widget. It would be easier to detect a click on your triangle...